# Winston wrote invalid characters to file

Tags: node.js, linux, file, winston

My logger was working fine, but suddenly my `logger.query` stopped working. It started returning some unknown character error as `result` while the `err` was still `null`.

I checked the file and found some weird characters between two logs.

gedit shows the characters as:

> \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00...
>   while notepad just shows blank space

I think it might have been in process of writing the file but was shutdown. Can anybody tell me the reason why this happened? Any way to fix the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by stripping out the null characters from the files when the problem came up.

I first try to `query` the logger normally. If I don't get an instance of `Error` for my `results`, then everything is fine. However, if I do get an instance of `Error`, then I strip out all my null characters and try again with a flag that says not to keep on trying on further failures.

The way I strip out the null characters is by using `sed`. I use `sed -i -e 's/\\x0//g' ${DATA_DIRECTORY}/logs/*.log` here, where `${DATA_DIRECTORY}/logs` is the path to my log files folder.

Here is a full example:

```js
public readonly read = async (retry = true) => {
    return new Promise<LogEntry[]>((resolve, reject) => {
        const options: QueryOptions = {...};
        let logs: LogEntry[];
        this.logger.query(options, (error, results) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            const rawWinstonLogs = results as {
                dailyRotateFile: DailyRotateFileEntry[];
            };
            // sometimes null bytes get written to a log file. In this
            // case, `reuslts.dailyRotateFile` is an Error object. If this
            // happens, try stripping the null characters from the file and
            // try again once
            if (rawWinstonLogs.dailyRotateFile instanceof Error) {
                // if it's not the first time retrying, just fail
                if (!retry) {
                    reject(rawWinstonLogs.dailyRotateFile);
                    return;
                }
                // strip the null characters out of the files
                exec(`sed -i -e 's/\\x0//g' ${DATA_DIRECTORY}/logs/*.log`);
                // try again
                resolve(this.read(false));
                return;
            }
            // if somehow we got here and this isn't a function, reject
            if (typeof rawWinstonLogs.dailyRotateFile.map !== 'function') {
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            logs = rawWinstonLogs.dailyRotateFile.map((logEntry, index) => {
                const entry: LogEntry = { ...logEntry, id: index };
                return entry;
            });
            resolve(logs);
        });
    });
};
```

**Note**: I only get this problem when my code shuts down un-gracefully. What I mean is I am loading this code onto a device, and when I switch off that device's power while its running, that's when Winston inserts the null characters. I start it back up and the null characters are always between the last message before the shutoff and the first message after the power comes back.

Comment: Here is a link to [a github issue](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/2241) about the problem for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I think it has something to do with `\00` being a `null` character internally.

I recently found this video regarding that, you might want to check it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fw5Cyh21TE

A possible fix could be to check the incoming String on `\00` and convert it with a string replace (haven't tested if that worked though)

Comment: but winston doesnt even give me that string. If it had, I would've just ignored the `\00`. The query callback didnt even give me `err`. It gave me `result` with error inside it.
Maybe i can fix the file in case this happens.